# Solution to Klein-Gordon equation in terms of $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{k}$

Tags: field-theory, fourier-transform, dimensional-analysis, klein-gordon-equation, absolute-units

A general solution to the Klein-Gordon equation can be written as:

$$\phi = \int d^3k \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^3 \sqrt{2\omega_k}} \left(a(\vec{k})e^{-i(\omega_kx_o-\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x})}+a^{\dagger}(\vec{k})e^{i(\omega_kx_0-\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x})}\right).$$

We can also write it as:

$$\phi = \int d^3p \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^3 \sqrt{2\omega_p}} \left(a(\vec{p})e^{-i(\omega_kx_o-\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x})}+a^{\dagger}(\vec{p})e^{i(\omega_kx_0-\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x})}\right).$$

Both solutions have exactly the same form, while $\vec{k}$ is wave vector and $\vec{p}$ is momentum. Is that so because $p=\hbar k$, and in natural units $p=k$? Also since $E=\hbar \omega$, so in natural units $\omega_p=E=\omega_k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The website doesn't allow a three character answer so the rest of this is filler :).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/366389)

Comment: The question was a yes or no question and I said yes. The OP should ask more before further commentary is warranted.